# flutter ListView take some items in itemCount parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

as we know we have `itemCount` in `ListView` widget, i have more than 100 items inside array and i want to take only 10 items from that, for example:

```
itemCount: _dashboardViewModel.media.where((element) => element.type=='images').length,
```

in that `length` is 100, how can i take only 10 item in `itamCount` parameter?

```
child: Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
  child: ListView.separated(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ...;
    },
    itemCount: _dashboardViewModel.media.where((element) => element.type=='images').length,
    separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 6.0,
          height: 6.0,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 5.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 15.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: Only 10 based on what? The first 10? The last 10?

Comment: Why don't you just create a new list or array with the elements that you want to display and then display *that* list?

Comment: @Locked from the first

Comment: You say you want 10 items, well what 10? What's the condition on which you want to choose those 10 items from a list of 100 items?

Comment: @Abbas.M They already specified that.

Comment: What have you tried? What's preventing you from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `sublist` method.

Like this.

```
itemCount: _dashboardViewModel.media.where((element) => element.type=='images').toList().sublist(0, 10).length,
```

Comment: I believe you forgot the `.length`, also I don't see how that's different from hardcoding a 10 if he already knows he wants exactly 10, or maybe a min between the list size and 10 to avoid errors if list is too small

Comment: @Abbas.M `length` is not a method. It's a getter. and I agree about the hardocoding.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore you're right, I edited it

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [take()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/take.html), which helps you to get the first n numbers you want in this case, `first 10 numbers`

`toList()` is not compulsory for this method, so removing it from the code will still give out the length.

**Pointer:** If you need a `List` object type specifically for some reason, then you might want to use `toList()`. But not in this case.

```
itemCount: _dashboardViewModel.media.where((element) => element.type=='images').take(10).length
```

Comment: The `toList` here is completely unecessary.

Comment: Well I agree with you @ChristopherMoore. But we can use it anyways, it will return the data into `list` items. Like `[1,2,3]`. if not defined: it will come like this `(1,2,3)`, basically in `set`. Doesn't make much difference. Thanks for pointing it out for me :)

Comment: There's just no point. It's an extra operation with no purpose.